# Skill Base Ability Score Changing Diplomacy from Charisma to Intelligence

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

I'm not sure if my google-fu is just off tonight or if there's a way to change the 3.X/Pathfinder skill Diplomacy from being a Charisma based Skill to an Intelligence based skill.

I'd prefer 3.X (including sources like Kingdoms of Kalamar) and Pathfinder to be open... as well as a few other not so specific sources like Green Ronin press, or Book of Erotic Fantasy, etc...

I'm trying not to homebrew something myself, or to at least use outher sources as a reference. I've already looked at the X to Y reference, but didn't find anything for changing Diplomacy form a Charisma based skill to Intelligence...

Answer (score 6):

If your game allows characters to be created with [traits](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/), Pathfinder includes two social traits that do this, and there's a few other similar effects.

### [Student of Philosophy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/student-of-philosophy/), social trait from *PPC: Quests and Campaigns*

> You can use your Intelligence modifier in place of your Charisma modifier on Diplomacy checks to persuade others and on Bluff checks to convince others that a lie is true. (This trait does not affect Diplomacy checks to gather information or Bluff checks to feint in combat).

This doesn't apply to absolutely all uses of Diplomacy, but it does extend the benefit to some uses of Bluff as well.

---

### [Clever Wordplay](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/clever-wordplay/), social trait from *PPC: Pathfinder Society Primer*

> Choose one Charisma-based skill. You attempt checks with that skill using your Intelligence modifier instead of your Charisma modifier.

This allows you to substitute Intelligence for Charisma entirely on any one Charisma-based skill, such as Diplomacy.

---

### The [Empiricist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/investigator/archetypes/paizo-investigator-archetypes/empiricist/), investigator archetype from *PRG: Advanced Class Guide*

The Empiricist's **Ceaseless Observation** class feature allows that:

> At 2nd level, an empiricist uses his Intelligence modifier instead of the skill’s typical ability for all Disable Device, Perception, Sense Motive, and Use Magic Device checks. He can also use his Intelligence modifier instead of Charisma on any Diplomacy checks made to gather information.

Which broadly allows you to substitute Intelligence on several skills, and specifically on Diplomacy checks to gather information but not other Diplomacy checks.

---

### [Ironclad Logic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/ironclad-logic/), feat from *PRG: Ultimate Intrigue*

This doesn't actually let you substitute Intelligence for Charisma generally, but it does represent leveraging your high Intelligence (Int 19 required) for a bonus to Diplomacy checks:

> You gain a +4 bonus on Diplomacy checks whenever you add your Charisma modifier on those checks.
>
> If you have at least 10 ranks in Diplomacy and an Intelligence score of 27 or more, this bonus increases to +8.

---

### [Inside Man](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/slayer/slayer-talents/rogue-genius-games-slayer-talents/inside-man), slayer talent from *Advanced Options: Slayer Talents & Lethalities* (third-party, Rogue Genius Games)

Besides a bunch of free class skills, the Slayer gets to substitute Intelligence on Diplomacy checks:

> Additionally the slayer uses his Intelligence modifier, rather than Charisma modifier, with Diplomacy checks.

Answer (score 3):

### [Orator (General Feat)](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Orator)

**Source** Advanced Class Guide pg. 152

You’re able to construct statements and commands that are much more convincing than their content would otherwise suggest.

**Prerequisites:** Skill Focus (Linguistics).

**Benefit:** You can use a Linguistics check in place of a Bluff check to tell a falsehood or conceal information, in place of a Diplomacy check to change the attitude of a 
creature, or in place of an Intimidate check to force a creature to cooperate. You must deliver your attempt in a language the target understands.

---

This effectively gives you Intelligence to common uses of Diplomacy, Bluff, and Intimidate instead of Charisma. It does so by allowing you to replace the checks with Linguistics checks, which are Intelligence-governed. This also gives you thrice the benefit per skill rank as you are getting the bonus across all three skills. However, it does not replace every use of those charisma-based checks; you cannot feint with Orator's Bluff roll, for example.

Answer (score 2):

[Student of Philosophy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/student-of-philosophy/) and [Clever Wordplay](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/clever-wordplay/) seems to do what you want for Pathfinder.